# List.Count returns 0 from button list

Tags: c#, list

When i try to access multiple buttons in buttons's list by foreach or for like in the following code it does nothing or pops the following error if i change `BtnsList` to 13 as the list size:

> "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."

```
for (int refresher = 0 ; refresher < BtnsList.Count - 1 ; refresher++)
{
     BtnsList[refresher].Text = "whatever";
}
```

I did that before:

```
BtnsList.Add(button1);
BtnsList.Add(button2);
BtnsList.Add(button3);
BtnsList.Add(button4);
BtnsList.Add(button5);
BtnsList.Add(button6);
BtnsList.Add(button7);
BtnsList.Add(button8);
BtnsList.Add(button9);
BtnsList.Add(button10);
BtnsList.Add(button11);
BtnsList.Add(button12);
```

So i cant see why `.count` returns 0.

Full relevant code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    static int[] Texters = new int[13];
    static List<Button> BtnsList = new List<Button>();


    static void Pressed(int a)
    {

        int b = a;
        while (Texters[a] > 0)
        {
            Texters[b + 1]++;

        }
        for (int refresher = 0 ; refresher < BtnsList.Count ; refresher++)
        {
           BtnsList[refresher].Text = "whatever";

        }

    }

    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }



    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (int tempInt in Texters)
        {
            Texters[tempInt] = 4;
        }
        foreach (Button btn in this.Controls)
        {
            btn.Text = "4";
        }
        BtnsList.Add(button1);
        BtnsList.Add(button2);
        BtnsList.Add(button3);
        BtnsList.Add(button4);
        BtnsList.Add(button5);
        BtnsList.Add(button6);
        BtnsList.Add(button7);
        BtnsList.Add(button8);
        BtnsList.Add(button9);
        BtnsList.Add(button10);
        BtnsList.Add(button11);
        BtnsList.Add(button12);


    }
```

Comment: If you added AFTER you did your for loop, you're not going to have a list to iterate in your for loop. Add your buttons before.

Comment: please show the full code in regards to the order of which you are doing things.. also you are writing the code and as a rule of thumb a good developer regardless of experience should know how to debug their own code.. start stepping through your code and logically you will quickly see where you went wrong..

Comment: note that < BtnsList.Count -1 is wrong. < BtnsList.Count is what you want.

Comment: This code alone cannot produce the error declared. If there are no items in the list then no loop will be performed.

Comment: [C# basics tutorial For Loops](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_for_loop.htm) I would suggest doing some reading on the basic fundamentals of C# programming also know that index positions in C# are `zero based ! one based`

Comment: What exactly is `BtnsList`? As it is initially defined.

Comment: I'm guessing (we only see a partial class so I'm not sure) that your buttons (button1 through button12) are not initialized yet when you are adding them, so all you're doing is `BtnsList.add(null)` 12 times.

Comment: I'm adding them at the form_load event...

Answer (score 2):

Add your buttons before you iterate through them in your for loop and that should solve your problem.

Comment: The adding happens before the loop.

Comment: Then as @pm100 said, it's probably because you have < BtnsList.Count -1 when it should be < BtnsList.Count.

Comment: Adjust your post so that I could see all of your relevant code, I might be able to help you better then.

Comment: See if adding all of your buttons in your form constructor will help, after InitializeComponent. Also, these buttons are initialized, right?